# Image upload javascript library with progress bar?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for an image upload javascript library that supports these requirements:

- No third party dependencies such as Jquery.
- Show progress bar
- image scaling
- drag & drop
- image validation etc

So far I've found the following options available.

- fineuploader.com/
- https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js
- https://github.com/23/resumable.js
- www.dropzonejs.com/

Do you know any other better library?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that "best" is pretty subjective (one man's owl is another man's nightingale), and this site doesn't just list "all kind of best". What's wrong with the options you've found already? What is missing? What would make a library "best" in your eyes?

Comment: Has the OP editted the question? Because it looks perfectly cromulent to me. Perhaps it could be un-held?